# What is an elegant way to prepend some text to a bibliography entry using \cite{} in revtex 4-1?

Tags: citing, revtex

I'm working with revTeX and using `\cite{AuthorName2011}` to refer to some piece of relevant literature.

This adds a number to the text and a bibliographic entry to the bibliography section.

I want to prepend some text (e.g. "For more details see ") to the bibliographic entry.

What is an elegant way to do that?

P.S. I'm using revTeX with the following options:

```
\documentclass[superscriptaddress,twocolumn,epsf,prb,amsmath,amssymb,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in the [REVTeX 4.1 Author's Guide](https://d22izw7byeupn1.cloudfront.net/files/revtex/auguide4-1.pdf)

```
 \cite{*[{Prepended text }] [{ appended text}] AuthorName2011}
```